# How to Print each row in the list table in a separate page. NetSuite Advanced PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, netsuite

I am trying to print each row in the picking ticket on a separate page and for now, am using the Row height to move each item to a new page but this is something not professional cuz when I made any change in the template the format is totally changed and this solution will not work so, I am looking for a style to make this solution more dynamic whatever the changes that may happen to the other tables in the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css property `page-break-after: always` for this purpose.

e.g.

```
<style>
   div.ps { page-break-after:always}
</style>
    ...
<div class="ps">
   ... ps details
</div>
```